# how to access a testsite which is mapped in host file using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to access a test url which is mapped in my host file using webdriver although when i access it manually it works fine. In my host file its mapped as below
10.18.xx.xxx    xxxxxx03.itsxxxx.net

When I access it via webdriver I get below error

This site can’t be reached

xxxxxx03.itsxxxx.net refused to connect.
Try:
Checking the connection
Checking the proxy and the firewall
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Please help.

Comment: how URL looks like means URL passing to WebDriver? provide complete URL to WebDriver

Comment: I use below urls and both work manually (https://xxxx03.itssxxx.net and https://xxxx03.itssxxx.net/)

Answer (score 0):

use complete URL

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.net  in driver.get
```

Comment: yes, i am using complete url like https:// xxxx03.itssxxx.net. When I navigate it again with wait of i sec then it works. so first time it gives refused to connection error as put in the question and when I navigate it again with 1 sec wait then it work and without wait doesnt work, dont know where the issue is